# import android.util.LOG; unused import statement android-studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

**import android.util.LOG unused import statement android studio**
[image: Error Image]

Hi i'm new to android studio and this is the tutorial i've tried to follow from thenewboston youtube tutorial which i got an error message like this. I've tried the solution on checking the auto import> add unambiguous imports on the fly and unchecking the optimize imports on the fly but it still shows the same error as the image shown. How do i resolve this? Sorry for asking such a question

Comment: The issue is that it can't find `LOG.i(...)`. Try using `Log.i(...)` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my import statement:

`import android.util.Log;`
Not `LOG`, Using `Log.e()` when you coding.

Answer (score 0):

It is `Log` not `LOG`, replace `LOG` with `Log` in import statement and everywhere below. And it would be better if you post the code, not the image on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Don't Worry.

Just change the

```
LOG.i(TAG, "TEXT ");
```

To

```
Log.i(TAG, "TEXT ");
```